# Invalidate single files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Sometimes IntelliJ IDEA chokes on an action and produces a lot of red errors as a result. For example, I do a "Refactor → Rename File...", and afterwards there are those errors, although nothing except the file name changed.

Is there a possibility to invalidate the cache *of just that file*. I.e., avoiding to use the hammer and call "File → Invalidate Caches".

Comment: [Not even for project](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6746), only entire cache can be invalidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close project and re-open project did help here.